# ADO.Net Destination connector

Tags: oracle, ssis, ado.net, etl

I'm looking into existing packages in SSIS for my team to streamline some of the ETL, and I came across a symbol which do not correspond to the connectors in the existing library. Has anyone come across the symbol that has the label of ADO destination below?

[image: ADO Destination icon]

From what I have seen thus far, ADO.Net Destination has a specific connector with its own symbol like the below

[image: ADO Destination Out of the box icon]

The package is purely extracting source data from oracle DB, and then re-ingest it to another oracle DB using the ADO.Net connectors.

Comment: That's just a name that can be changed by the user. Check the component's properties (select the component and hit F4). What is its type?

Comment: This is a custom component https://www.slideshare.net/wolfgangstrasser5/professional-recycling-ssis-custom-control-flow-components-with-visual-studio-community

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first image is showing a custom component *(based on the icon)* and the label ADO destination is meaningless since it is wrote by the developer.

To check the component type, click on it and press <kbd>F4</kbd> to show the properties tab, then check the component type on the top of properties.